# Jupyterhub: where is get_config defined and how do I create a custom Authenticator?

Tags: python, authentication, jupyter

I want to create a jupyterhub installation that uses a custom redirect to authenticate the user.  The user would enter the url to our Jupyterhub, be redirected to a separate authentication system, then returned to the app, bypassing login.html.  It seems initially a lot of hacking would be needed on the actual Jupyterhub source code to make this work.

From what I understand currently we would need customize jupyterhub/jupyterhub/handlers/login.py jupyterhub/auth.py.  We wanted to avoid that and use the officially supported mechanisms.  I thought maybe I could create my own Authenticator for use in a config file as in

```
c = get_config()
c.Authenticator.stuffGoesHere
```

and implement my own:

```
class LoginHandler(BaseHandler)  // login.py
```

in addition to

```
class Authenticator(LoggingConfigurable):  // auth.py
```

But I don't even see clearly how to do this as I cannot figure out where

```
 get_config()
```

is implemented and how to override this.  Am I overthinking this?  Whats the solution to wanting a separate system to handle the login (we can get the username from this external system for docker provisioning etc for dockerspawner).  Btw, where is get_config actually defined?

Comment: did you find solution for using get_config()?

Answer (score 3):

The `get_config` is defined here: https://github.com/ipython/traitlets/blob/c5c9166373041dd561d8ad86e8990ae844d26306/traitlets/config/loader.py#L483-L501

And the reason you can use it directly without importing first is `py3compat.execfile`.

Back to your need, what you should do is create your `CustomizedAuthenticator` class which extends the `jupyterhub.auth.Authenticator`. And use it with:

```
c.JupyterHub.authenticator_class = CustomizedAuthenticator
```